# Docker apache2 /etc/hosts ignored works only with localhost

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, apache2, hosts

I have successfully set up Docker, Apache2, PHP in separate containers. I can access my website via http://localhost:8080.

The problem I have is to do with /etc/hosts file (I think). Let's take a look at my docker-compose file:

```
apache2:
    build:
      context: ./apache2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache2
    image: httpd:2.4.39-alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/srv/app
    extra_hosts:
      - "custom-website-name.local:127.0.0.1"
```

As you can see I did add the extra host in there and it even appears in /etc/hosts file in the container. However, no matter what I do and what changes do I make(manually on the LIVE container and in config) I can't force my setup to recognize that new host.

I also have vhost config in place:

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.custom-website-name.local
    ServerAlias custom-website-name.local
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://webapp:9000/srv/app/public/$1
    DocumentRoot /srv/app/public
    <Directory /srv/app/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

Which is copied into the config. It all seems to be not enough at this point I can access my website only via `http://localhost:8080` and `http://custom-website-name.local:8080` gives me `This site can’t be reached` which means that new name was not resolved.

The question of course is: what am I missing? I have no clue what else I can try (and I did try the whole bunch of things).

EDIT:

I did add an entry to local (non docker) `/etc/hosts` as well - did not help.

Comment: Try reversing the order of the entries. They should look like this in your /etc/hosts file:    
127.0.0.1    custom-website-name.local

Comment: I see where you are coming from. Docker-compose format is indeed weird a bit here but what I have under ```extra-hosts``` key seems is added into ```/etc/hosts``` in reversed(correct order) so - 127.0.0.1 my.domain

Comment: See comment below re: local /etc/hosts file. It certainly can be a bit confusing! :c)

Comment: Shouldn't you include `/etc/hosts` as a volume?

Comment: I think volume's are mainly used for storage/persistence, although I could easily be wrong on that

Comment: Volumes are good for stuff like databases. We don't want to keep configs in volumes so I think @user6854465 is correct. As for ```/etc/hosts``` I should be clearer on that(my bad, sorry guys): I did both my local one and container. I did try different browsers  and incognito mode. No luck so far.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: So just to confirm, the issue is that you want to access the website with this custom domain from the _host_? What did you try and put in your local /etc/hosts file?

Comment: @user6854465 - yep - every time I make a change to the config I am tearing containers down and rebuilding them. 

@Jonnix - yes that is correct - I want to have access via my custom url so at some point I can have many websites and it will be easier for me to have it this way. So this is what went to my local (non docker) /etc/hosts: ```127.0.0.1       custom-website-name.local``` - looks right doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the server inside the docker image - I meant whatever server you are running locally that is interpretting your hosts file

Comment: I'm afraid I misunderstood something. I am not using any local servers. The only server instance(apache2) lives in the docker container. Other than that - there is only local ```/etc/hosts``` file involved. Nothing else - which works fine if we don't look at this unfortunate host.

Comment: Can you ping the domain from the command line? Can you e.g. `telnet` into port `8080`? Out of interest, does `http://127.0.0.1:8080` work can't think of why it wouldn't, but no harm in checking? Also with the host in place, what is the full error from the browser?

Comment: 8080 will be mapped to 80 on the host, but I'm not sure why 127.0.0.1 custom-website-name.local in the local /etc/hosts file isn't being picked up. Might be a bit of a longshot, but maybe try changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost?

Comment: @Jonnix I can get successful response from ```curl http://127.0.0.1``` as well as from ```curl http://localhost```. I don't have that protocol(telnet) available at hand in my shell.

I can access the website both ways from the browser as well. Whe I am trying to use my custom name I am getting ```This site can’t be reached robert-kabat.local’s server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for robert kabat local 8080
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED```

Comment: And pinging the custom domain? I'm assuming you just didn't type the :8080 from the curl bits?

Comment: Did you set a dns?  
(Check out: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-config-the-dns-for-a-container/52395)

Comment: @user6854465 - just tried your idea - didn't work for me. 
@Jonnix ```curl: (6) Could not resolve host:```

I get this feeling that this is some really dodgy issue and hosts are ok.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, it looks more like a local networking issue or something really weird for it to ignore /etc/hosts all together. I hesitate to suggest turning your machine off and on again?

Comment: lol, couldn't get The IT Crowd (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd) out of my head but didn't want to let it out :cD

Comment: I didn't do any DNS stuff but (I am probably wrong) isn't that working if I can use localhost instead 127.0.0.1?
@Jonnix I would not be surprised if that worked. Well, it is time to pull off IT crowd - brb guys :)

Comment: /etc/hosts is _usually_ queried quite early on in DNS resolution, so in that respect you have done some "DNS stuff". 127.0.0.1 doesn't need to resolve, and sure, localhost working implies that at least some of the process is working.

Comment: Hmm so that did not help. Can I maybe specify the ports in hosts file? Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: No no, ports aren't dealt with in there. Might be getting to the end of what I can realistically suggest. Can you check the permissions on /etc/hosts and show us what the value is for the `hosts` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? Btw, what OS / distro are you on?

Comment: That is one weird issue. Well as for the permissions ```rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     247  7 Aug 21:11 hosts``` However I do not see any ```nsswitch.conf``` nor ```dnsswitch.conf```

I will keep trying to play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

[HERE](https://forums.docker.com/t/option-network-mode-host-in-docker-compose-file-not-working-as-expected/51682) you can find a solution posted by a user named **octesian**. I looked only briefly at the entire thing but it seems to be some weird undocumented docker quirk. I do recommend to go deeper into networking documentation of Docker.

It looks like in the build section of apache2 service I had to add `network: host` so:

```
apache2:
    build:
      network: host
      context: ./apache2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache2
    image: httpd:2.4.39-alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

I bet it is not perfect and will cause different issues down the line when I decide to introduce more websites but for now, it is a success and valid solution.